# Android Studio 1.2.2, build successful but no apk in build/output?

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, apk

I began a few days ago with Android Studio 1.2.2 in order to make some simple app by curiosity. I did a first one and was able to get the .apk without any problem in app>build>output.

But since yesterday I can't get any .apk in output folder although build is successful. Maybe have I done an unintentional mistake ? I see .gradle and output directories are excluded (folder is red) and I've got the problem since it is, why are those excluded and what would be the manipulation to solve this ?

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsh1h.jpg)

I've searched and read some threads but didn't manage to find the solution to my problem, I guess it must be simple but as a noob I still can't figure some things :)

Thanks a lot for your help,

Aaron

Comment: Can you post your gradle logs as well?

Comment: Any success? Im having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

After successful build, **run** your application. Then you will get the **APK folder** inside of the **app/build** folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `app/build.gradle:` to `android` section:

```
signingConfigs {

        release {

            storeFile file('../../android-release-key.keystore')
            storePassword "pass"
            keyAlias "alias"
            keyPassword "keypass"

        }
    }
buildTypes {

        release {

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Comment: Of course you should change `storePassword "pass", keyAlias "alias", keyPassword "keypass"`

Answer (score 0):

By default Android Studio 1.2.2 store apks in build-> artifacts->project_name->aproject_name.apk

Answer (score 0):

The Executing tasks of make project command in Android Studio 1.2.2 are different from those in the previous version. In 1.2.2 , the executing tasks are [:app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]  while in previous version the executing tasks are [:app:assembleDebug, :lib:bundleDebug]. That is why you can not find .apk.You can get the .apk by running your application.

Answer (score 0):

Open messages tab then open Information:See complete output in console 
`This will show you more details about what happened`

Answer (score 0):

I was using Azure DevOps and my case issue was related to gradle task that I was providing.

Wrong task:

```
- task: Gradle@3
  displayName: 'gradlew $(Build.DefinitionName)'
  inputs:
    tasks: 'bundleskyandroid'
```

Changed to assembleskyandroid and it worked.

```
- task: Gradle@3
  displayName: 'gradlew $(Build.DefinitionName)'
  inputs:
    tasks: 'assembleskyandroid'
```

My build.gradle file

```
productFlavors 
        { 
          skyandroid 
          {
              applicationId 'io.xxxxxx.skyandroid'
              versionCode 7
              versionName '1.10'
              manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}"]
              signingConfig signingConfigs.skyandroid
          }
        }
```